# Transferring data to the end of a transaction with the Shopp Plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, e-commerce, plugin-shopp

I'm using the Shopp Plugin, and basically, I need to send an email to a unique email address field that I've created on the front end. The transaction has to complete fully before sending it. I mean, money has to have been transferred successfully, etc. I've attached the fields to a particular set of products, and I can move the data between pages (via $_POST of course), ie; Product -> Cart -> Checkout... It's after this that's the problem. Landing on the Thank you page or whatever, I don't have access to the finalized list of items that were bought, via the $_POST method. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Seems like an awkward way to go about this. Can't you use the shopp_order_notifications filter?

Take a look at https://shopplugin.net/api/shopp_order_notifications/ for the docs.

Comment: Right, that's true. Definitely part of what I'm doing. But my problem is on that page, how do I call the products that were successfully ordered? I need that data (the IDs, etc.) so that I can know what information to process in my function.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to say *in that function...

Comment: You need to take a look at shopp_order_line_data ( $order, $line, $name ) which returns information about the line items for a given order no. That way you can process each line item.

Comment: Ah, ok. That helps out a lot!